# Filter Asana Project by Team using API

Tags: asana

I'm writing a standalone application to interface with Asana using the API to extract data and I wanted to just download a list of the projects within a specific team.

All I seem to be able do is query for all projects within the organization meaning I would then have to parse the downloaded data to just get those assigned with a specific team ID

Is it possible to returned a more limited data set like this upfront?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing all there is. What you're seeing [in the documentation](http://developer.asana.com/documentation/#projects) is all they got.

Your best bet, if you want this feature added, is to either get in the [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/asana-developer-preview) where the developers hang out, or hit up their [contact form](https://asana.com/support).

Answer (score 0):

Good idea! I'll add it to our wish list.

In the meantime, if you are only interested in finding the projects by a given team's ID, try adding `?opt_fields=team` to your projects query. It'll significantly reduce the number of calls you need to make by including the team's ID in each project! (You can add any other fields you need, comma-delimited. So if you want the team and the name, you can do `?opt_fields=team,name`.)